# How to enable stereoscopic output over hdmi1.4

Tags: linux, debian, hdmi, xorg, xorg.conf

On Windows®, it’s a checkbox in the screen resolution setting dialog, but how to do the same on Linux.

If there’s no generic solution available, both my nvidia geforce and intel gpu support outputing stereoscopic signal over their own hdmi port on Windows®.

Comment: Please note the question isn’t about having an application that use stereoscopy, but sending a non monoscopic signal to the monitor first.

Comment: Which GPUs do you have exactly? There's relatively new support for NV50+ (G80+) hardware in `nouveau`, see [here](https://github.com/skeggsb/nouveau/commit/354f1a86b9c5fbf59110fea26717a527e9a4064e), but apparently they don't support older hardware. The proprietary `nvidia` driver supports at least the Quadro line. Intel seems also to be support, but I'm not sure about the model range. Try `xrandr --verbose` and see if some properties are shown for your hardware.

Comment: @dirkt gtx 1070 and intel 530. I just know everything works find on windows

Comment: Please edit question with output of `xrandr --verbose` and `lspci -nn`.